# Compare lines of a 'specific' column and join the other columns if the lines of the 'specific' colum match

Tags: bash, file, perl

I have a tab delimited file with three columns (GO ID, Biological process, Gene), and I want to compare the lines of the third column and if they match I want to join their respective first and second columns. I'm kinda new programming and I have tried a lot of not efficient ways and not getting the results I want.

Here is an example of the desired output.

Input

```
GO:0007155      cell adhesion   ACHE
GO:0022610      biological adhesion     ACHE
GO:0007155      cell adhesion   ADAM19
GO:0022610      biological adhesion     ADAM19
GO:0007155      cell adhesion   AMBN
GO:0022610      biological adhesion     AMBN
```

Output:

```
GO:0007155;GO:0022610      cell adhesion;biological adhesion   ACHE
GO:0007155;GO:0022610      cell adhesion;biological adhesion   ADAM19
GO:0007155;GO:0022610      cell adhesion;biological adhesion   AMBN
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: tab delimited? Because it looks like your 3rd col is "adhesion", lol ;)

Comment: Yes, is tab delimited, the second column is a biological process, and the third one the gene involved in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using the ever-useful [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) plus some massaging to get the output in the format you want:

```
$ datamash -g 3 collapse 1 collapse 2 < input.tsv | \
   awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } { print $2, $3, $1 }' | tr , ';'   
GO:0007155;GO:0022610   cell adhesion;biological adhesion   ACHE
GO:0007155;GO:0022610   cell adhesion;biological adhesion   ADAM19
GO:0007155;GO:0022610   cell adhesion;biological adhesion   AMBN
```

(This assumes the file is sorted based on the third column like it is in your sample data)

---

And in perl:

```
$ perl -F"\t" -lane 'push @{$genes{$F[2]}}, [@F[0,1]];
                     END { $,="\t";
                           for (sort keys %genes) {
                             print join(";", map { $_->[0] } @{$genes{$_}}),
                                   join(";", map { $_->[1] } @{$genes{$_}}),
                                   $_ } }' input.tsv
GO:0007155;GO:0022610   cell adhesion;biological adhesion   ACHE
GO:0007155;GO:0022610   cell adhesion;biological adhesion   ADAM19
GO:0007155;GO:0022610   cell adhesion;biological adhesion   AMBN
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a tab-delimited copy of your data.

```
$: cat cols
GO:0007155      cell adhesion   ACHE
GO:0022610      biological adhesion     ACHE
GO:0007155      cell adhesion   ADAM19
GO:0022610      biological adhesion     ADAM19
GO:0007155      cell adhesion   AMBN
GO:0022610      biological adhesion     AMBN

$: declare -A A B C # associative arrays - "lookup tables"
$: tab=$'\t'        # just to make it easier to see it embedded
$: while IFS=$'\t' read a b c
   do A[$c]="${A[$c]};$a"
      B[$c]="${B[$c]};$b"
   done < cols      # stack cols
$: for c in "${!A[@]}"
   do echo "${A[$c]#;}$tab${B[$c]#;}$tab$c" # strip leading semicolons
   done
GO:0007155;GO:0022610   cell adhesion;biological adhesion       ADAM19
GO:0007155;GO:0022610   cell adhesion;biological adhesion       AMBN
GO:0007155;GO:0022610   cell adhesion;biological adhesion       ACHE
```

Did order of output matter?
If you need them alphabetical, for example, you could use this:

```
$: for c in $( printf "%s\n" "${!A[@]}" | sort )
   do echo "${A[$c]#;}$tab${B[$c]#;}$tab$c"
   done
```